# Trying to locate a sound file but it can't be located and running the code gets this error(GET file:(file path here) net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

Tags: javascript, directory, path

I tried adding (../) (../../) and also tried using the Path Intellisense extension which located it but the error still appears

this is how the extension located it

```
const hitSound = new Audio('../sounds/Ta Da-SoundBible.com-1884170640.mp3.extension');
```

I have the same error earlier and I wrote the full path starting from the drive name 
`cardImage.src = 'B:/Html, CSS & Js/js excersing/photos/KS.png'` and it worked but when I tried it on the code above it didn't work

Comment: Did you try '.mp3' instead of '.mp3.extension" ?

Comment: yes and sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

If the path `'../sounds/Ta Da-SoundBible.com-1884170640.mp3.extension'` in your javascript/html file would be correct, it would mean the following: The directory that contains the directory where your javascript/html file is located also contains a directory `sounds` where your sound file resides.

For a start, copy the sound file into the same directory as your javascript/html file and load it with

```
const hitSound = new Audio('Ta Da-SoundBible.com-1884170640.mp3.extension');
```

The whitespace in the filename (the blank between *Ta* and *Da*) could also be a problem, so I suggest you also rename the file.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.............tried to put the original sound file to the same directory as the html file and didn't work and tried to put the sound folder containing the sound file and also didn't work ....should I put the index.html and the script.js in the same directory? sorry for the late reply

Comment: 1. Remove the whitespace in the filename, better yet: give it a simple name like x.mp3. 2. Use an absolute path /x.mp3, and move the file into the root directory of your web server / virtual host.